# Keycloak - Use legacy authentication system in a native mobile app

Tags: jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services

We are running some tests on Keycloak to implement it on our company and I am are wondering what is the best approach to make Keycloak interact with our legacy system.

In our scenario, we have a native login interface and we are going to use `direct grant` - we are not going to authorization code flow / redirect flow using a browser and we **don't** have any kind of social login.

The other point is: we must to keep our native interface.

Based on that, what is the best/right approach to implement this flow? I have set my client on Keycloak with direct grant but the problem is that every user must exists in Keycloak. Isn't possible to use Keycloak as a "token emissor" instead of IDP?

In case of Keycloak must be an IDP, what is the right approach to allow Keycloak log in legacy system? Should I implement a custom Identity Provider? Will mobile make a login request to Keycloak or to legacy system?

Comment: I dont think token emissor way is possible. Only way i think to do this is using service account for a client. But of course then only one account is used which i believe you dont want.

Did you check out this video-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGp4HUKikts 
This helped me initially in setting up.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak must somehow be able to either authenticate the user or delegate the authentication of the user to a federated identity provider. A few options:

1. If you want to use Keycloak as an identity provider, you could do
   this by migrating your user base to Keycloak, or by making use of
   User Storage Federation, which means Keycloak will use your existing
   user database as a source. In this case, the login interface will be
   a Keycloak interface (which you can customize to your wishes). See:
   https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation
2. Another option is to convert your legacy system into an identity
   provider that complies with either the OIDC or SAML protocol, and
   set it up as an identity provider for Keycloak. In this case you can
   keep your existing login interface, but it will probably require
   quite some changes to your legacy system. See:
   https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker